# Css Find file extension

Tags: css, href

I am trying to add word, excel, pdf icons before file name based on file extension using css.
But my Hyperlink is encrypted and does not have valid extension. So I have to check if content has file extension then add icon.

Could some one please help me on this. Here is the code  [Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3uwvg/)

```
table tr td a[href$=".docx"]:before {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    content: "test";
    background: url(http://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/text-file-icon.png) repeat;
}



<td><a href="/GetDetails?Area=&amp;fileIdentificationKey=clgcuRNDkR6DeGqJY5l%2FZH3oyGA%2FRbrh2FXukJJ8QuC4sdmyXXwxq0zLQQfXPKC55kJda9654lUIwKQ9ETDzkFT1ep97FWplqHncKJdRL8sciOqriVqAD6AT10KjZFMC"> Request.docx</a>
</td>
```

Comment: You don't have `docx` in your `href`.. so that is not going to work.

Comment: Can I read .docx in content inside a tag

Comment: Don't think you can. Can you not add `.docx` in your `href`? Than it would work.

Comment: or add a class with the extension, or add a data-attribute with the extension